# Javascript and JQuery for loop on array to create list

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Html:

```
<p>Order</p>
<div>
<ul data-role="listview" id="myorder"></ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
itemName = ["beer1", "beer2", "beer3", "beer4"];
itemQty = [0, 2, 0, 4];

for ( var i=0, len=itemName.length; i<len; ++i) { 
    if (itemQty[i] > 0) {
        var listItem = document.createElement("li");
        listItem.innerHTML = itemName[i] + "    Qty:" + itemQty[i];
        $('#myorder').append(listItem);
        $('#myorder').listview('refresh');
    }
}
```

I know its staring me right in the face but why is this only showing my first instance of `Qty > 0`?

http://jsfiddle.net/Sptx7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error here:

```
$('#myorder').listview('refresh');
```

since `listview` is `undefined`, so the code terminates.

---

Here's your fiddle with that line commented out: http://jsfiddle.net/Sptx7/2/

As you can see, it renders both list items.